# Excel - Lookup and Match Values with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vlookup

Currently have the following excel table

[image]

I would like to do the following

I want to write a IF statement or something else which would do this:

if (the value in service 4 for company 1 is 1, and the value in service 1 for company 1 is also 1, then copy the value 1 to a new column)

how can one do this in excel ?

If the matching does not exist then copy 0 or nothing

Comment: It's unclear from your question, what should be the **desired / expected result**. For example, in your table, the first instance of Company1 should return 1, however the second should return 0. Is the desired result two lines, in which one is 1 and other is 0 or a congregate of those two that ends in logical `AND` or maybe even `OR`? **I voted to close the question as unclear until this is specified.**

Comment: 2 seperate lines, one after the other, so first row is 1 and second row is 0 - please help

Comment: In that case, @SolarMike 's answer will do.

Comment: What about in a single line?

Comment: His solution is in a single line..

Comment: i mean if i want to match on multiple criteria, e.g. check values in one column, then check values in another column>?

Comment: @DataScience have you tried my answer? If you have the data on 1 row as you showed -- I assumed each line was an independent instance.

Comment: forget it - io will repost question more clearly?

Comment: @DataScience my answer is looking at two columns for the "1" as you requested.

Comment: will repost for more clarity - i think its more complicated please see new post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: not used to people flagging their own question as a possible duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
=IF(AND(B2=1,E2=1)=TRUE,1,0)
```

as based on :
[image]

Or you could use:

```
=IF(SUM(B2,E2)=2,1,0)
```

which achieves the same thing.

Comment: you don't need the =True part.  And(B2-1,E2=1) is enough

Comment: While this is technically a functional answer, I do kind of suspect that the data OP provided here was just an example and you have to account for the fact that the data can contain more than a single row per company (hence even in his example, one instance of company 1 shoulde result in true and one in false (1) and (0). It's not really a knock against your answer, but more of lacking details in the original question

Comment: @ForwardEd, good point and quite right, but I did it to make it clear for the OP.

Comment: Basically, your answer should be fine.  Here is some shorthand:  =AND(B2=1,E2=1)*1 or to make it unclear what is going on =(B2=1)*(E2=1)*1

Comment: I take that back since any answer is dependent on what the new version of the question becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put the company name that you want to check in G1 you could use the following

```
=--AND(VLOOKUP(G1,$A$2:$E$5,2,0)=1,VLOOKUP(G1,$A$2:$E$5,5,0)=1)
```

For you results of just needing 1 or 0 the above would work as true will evaluate to 1 and false will evaluate to 0.

However if you wanted some other result other than 1 and 2 I would change the formula to:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(G1,$A$2:$E$5,2,0)=1,VLOOKUP(G1,$A$2:$E$5,5,0)=1),"True Result","False Result")
```

Comment: Hi Ed, I get the feeling we are trying to answer a question that is about to be changed as per the OP's comments...